# Rcpp: continued fractions and precision

Tags: rcpp, continued-fractions

I am struggling about floating points in `Rcpp` and how to get the numeric output from continued fractions in a numeric vector.

Here is my demo code:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('NumericVector signC() {
    NumericVector out1(3);
    out1[0]=round(0.888888888);
    out1[1]=round(1/3);
    out1[2]=1/3;
    return out1;
}')
```

The output from my demo code:

```
> signC()
[1] 1 0 0
```

I am wondering why `1/3` was convert to be 0 and how to get `0.3333333` from `1/3`? The `1/3` was working fine under R environment.

Thanks, I appreciate any replies in advance!

Comment: In short, C and C++ are a different ("typed") language, and `1/3` behaves differently: it is an integer-only division whereas R casts up to double. So here you want `1.0/3.0` (or having just one as double suffices too:  `1.0/3`).

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel. I really appreciate you helping me understand C++.

Comment: My pleasure.  These are the little things we all banged our heads against at some point. Live, and learn, and share.  Cheers.